# Is there any Payment Gateway that support Alipay and WeChat pay in a single integration in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

I'm not sure whether this question can be asked here but I don't see any other options. So please excuse me. 
I've been searching for quite sometime to find a suitable Payment gateway that supports both Alipay and WeChat pay in a singe integration in **Magento2**. So far I couldn't find any. So it would of great help if I could have some expert suggestions regarding the same. Please suggest suitable modules.

Comment: Look at this one if it can help https://magecomp.com/magento-2-alipay-cross-border.html

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned alipay and wechat pay, so you must target China. You can contact alipay and wechat directly and they should have their own magento payment plugin, however, its too much hassle and it will cost you much time if you go directly to them.

Answer (score 0):

did you find the Alipay and Wechat Pay extension for your Magento 2? Here are WeChat Pay and Alipay published at Magento Marketplace and both two work quite well with Magento 2 CE/EE. 
FYI: https://marketplace.magento.com/silksoftwarecorp-wechatpay.html
https://marketplace.magento.com/silksoftwarecorp-alipay.html